# NSCopying & Inheritance

Tags: objective-c

Please have a look on following code :------- .h

```
@interface BankAccount : NSObject<NSCopying>
{
    double accountBalance;
    long accountNumber;
    NSString *CustomerName;
    NSString *AccountType;
}

-(void) setAccount: (long) y andBalance: (double) x;
-(void) setCustomerName: (NSString*) name andAccountType: (NSString*) type;
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;

@end

@interface Savings : BankAccount
{
    int number;
    NSString *Offer;
}
-(void) setSavingNumber: (uint8_t) num andOffer: (NSString*) offer;
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
@end
```

---------- .m

```
@implementation BankAccount

-(void) setAccount: (long) y andBalance: (double) x
{
    accountNumber = y;
    accountBalance = x;
}
-(void) setCustomerName: (NSString*) name andAccountType: (NSString*) type
{
    CustomerName = name;
    AccountType = type;
}

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    BankAccount *accountCopy = [[BankAccount allocWithZone: zone] init];
    [accountCopy setAccount: accountNumber andBalance: accountBalance];
    [accountCopy setCustomerName:CustomerName andAccountType:AccountType];
    return accountCopy;
}

@end

@implementation Savings
-(void) setSavingNumber: (uint8_t) num andOffer: (NSString*) offer
{
    number = num;
    Offer = offer;
}

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    Savings * clone = [super copyWithZone:zone];
    [clone setSavingNumber:number andOffer:Offer];************** error *********
    return clone;
}

@end
```

When run this code::::::

```
Savings* account1;
Savings* account2;

account1 = [[Savings alloc] init];
[account1 setAccount:10 andBalance:1000.10];
[account1 setCustomerName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Deepak"] andAccountType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Savings"]];
[account1 setSavingNumber:2001 andOffer:@"Bad"];    
account2 = [account1 copy];
```

#

i dont know what is wrong with the code please help me. thanks in advance.

Thanks 
Deepak

Comment: Please format the code and ask a question. What is the current behavior, what would be the expected one.

Answer (score 30):

Your base `copyWithZone:` method should look like this:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    // change this line to use [self class]
    BaseClass *base = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];

    // copy base members:
    // ...

    return base;
}
```

Your derived `copyWithZone:` methods should look like this:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    DerivedClass *derived = [super copyWithZone:zone];

    // copy derived members:
    // ...

    return derived;
}
```

Also make sure sure you are making deep copies of strong references and shallow copies of weak references. Thus to for example copy members of type `NSString` and `NSArray` (each one with strongly referenced members and one with weak) do:

```
derived.strongString    = [[strongString copyWithZone:zone] autorelease];
derived.weakString      = weakString;
derived.strArrWStrVals  = [[strArrWStrVals copyWithZone:zone] autorelease];
derived.strArrWWeakVals = [[[NSArray allocWithZone:zone]
                            initWithArray:strArrWWeakVals] autorelease];
derived.weakArray       = weakArray;
```

(Usually weak members are also assigned/retained and strong variables are copied.)

Take note that because of this you should not use `initWithMyself:` type methods to copy data.

Comment: copyWithZone doesn't necessarily return a deep copy. Have a look at the Prototype pattern. It uses the NSCopying protocol in conjunction with NSArchiver and NSUnarchiver to make deep copying an easy task.

Comment: +1 for the `[self class]` in the base class allocWithZone. Doomed without that!

Comment: In many stackoverflow questions NSCopying is explained, but somehow they missed highlighting use of [self class].

Answer (score 1):

Ok first, your test code is bad because you set a saving number of 2001 in an 8 bit integer. Second, your code does not run because you're trying to call setSavingNumber:andOffer: on a BankAccount instead of an Saving object so it can't find the selector for this method at run time. Thanks David for pointing that out.

When implementing BankAccount::copyWithZone, you used the alloc-init and you returned the object which is fine. When implementing Savings::copyWithZone, you call super copyWithZone. What you get is an object of type BankAccount so you cannot use setSavingNumber:andOffer: on it. Since you used the alloc-init in the base class, you should also use the alloc-init and setMethods in the Savings class.

To avoid duplicating code, I'd recomment implementing an initWithBankAccount in BankAccount and the same in Savings.

Then in the copyWithZone, you'd have

```
return [[BankAccount allocWithZone:zone] initWithBankAccount:self];
```

and

```
return [[Savings allocWithZone:zone] initWithSavings:self];
```

Although you must make sure that in initWithSavings you call either

```
self = [super initWithBankAccount:savings];
```

or you call straight init and you copy the base member initialization.

Have a look at [Implementing object copy](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmImplementCopy.html) from Memory management programming guide.

Comment: Unlike C++ or C, the dynamic nature of objective-c will allow for unhandled messages to an object, but will fail at runtime (as opposed to compilation, as you mention). Please update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: The problem with calling `initWithBankAccount:` in `BankAccount`'s `copyWithZone` is that it will not return those members as deep copies. This may or may not give problems for you later on.

Comment: Of course this is fine if all the members happen to be weak references and no copies needed. But take care for instance if you want to use a class as a key in a `NSDictionary` or use them in `NSSet`, then changing the values that the ordering relies on can give problems/errors.